# ReadList can't read from file containing high-precision Reals

Tags: import, precision-and-accuracy

I want to read a file which contains seven columns of real numbers. Mathematica seems to have a problem with the high precision I need.

My code:

```
solFile = OpenRead["sol_Je9"]; 
data = ReadList[solFile, {Real, Real, Real, Real, Real, Real, Real}];
Close[solFile];
```

The error messages:

> General::digit: Digit at position 1 in -239.916104094628030 is too large to be used in base 10. 
>   ReadList::readn: Invalid real number found when reading from sol_Je9.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Apparently it needs the numbers to be in Fortran format...

Comment: Does `Number` instead of `Real` work?

Comment: @ssch: Number gives the same error

Comment: @cormullion: I generate this output in matlab. I would like to keep this format, but if I got no other option I also can change the output format of matlab...

Comment: @Thomas Can you post the file?

Comment: Have you considered `Import` as alternative `ReadList`?

Comment: @Thomas you're only 1 digit too long: a file with `-239.91610409462803` -type numbers reads OK... :) But I'd use `Import` myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `Record` and one of the options of `ReadList`

```
data = ReadList["filename", Table[Record, {7}], RecordSeparators -> {"\t", "\n"}]
```

Then use `ToExpression` to convert the elements (since they have `Head` `String`) to `Reals`.

```
ToExpression[data]
```

Or combine both into one line

```
 data = ToExpression @ ReadList["filename", Table[Record, {7}], RecordSeparators -> {"\t", "\n"}]
```

Note that I used tabs (`"\t"`) as one of my `RecordSeparators`, since you haven't posted the files, so I just copied that number and created a look-alike file. You'll have to read in the first few lines of your file and use `FullForm` and `InputForm` to see what `RecordSeparators` you should use. But this should work.

**EDIT**
For completeness here is how you can use `InputForm` to view the structure of your file and determine what `RecordSeparators` to use.

You can `Read` in the first three lines of your file as follows:

```
ReadList["filename", String, 3]
```

In my made up file, here is what I get:

```
{" -239.916104094628030234   -239.916104094628030543     \
-239.916104094628030233", " -239.916104094628030345  \
-239.916104094628030570  -239.916104094628030355", " \
-239.916104094628030678  -239.916104094628030442     \
-239.916104094628030654"}
```

Then using `InputForm` gives:

```
{" -239.916104094628030234\t -239.916104094628030543\t -239.916104094628030233", 
 " -239.916104094628030345\t -239.916104094628030570\t -239.916104094628030355", 
 " -239.916104094628030678\t -239.916104094628030442\t -239.916104094628030654"}
```

And you can see that "`\t`" is visible.

Now using

```
data = ToExpression@ReadList["filename", Table[Record, {3}], RecordSeparators -> {"\t", "\n"}]
```

Gives:

```
   {{-239.916104094628030234, -239.916104094628030543, -239.916104094628030233},  
   {-239.916104094628030345, -239.916104094628030570, -239.916104094628030355}, 
{-239.916104094628030678, -239.916104094628030442, -239.916104094628030654}}
```

Now, `Head[data[[1,1]]]` gives `Real`