# ReadList can't read correctly

Tags: bugs, import

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 9.0.1**

---

I'm trying to load some data into Mathematica from some files generated by fortran. But ReadList seems can't get the number correct.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
ReadList[StringToStream@" 0.000000000000000000E+00
   0.490953850725349982E-10
   0.135898165173686872E-09
   0.264968686580858939E-09", Number]
(*{0.,4.9095385072534998*10^12709,1.3589816517368687*10^12708,2.6496868658085894*10^12708}*)
```

In the documentation, it promised that:

> ReadList can handle numbers that are given in Fortran-like "E"
>   notation. Thus, for example, ReadList will read 2.5E+5 as 2.5*10^5.
>   Note that ReadList can handle numbers with any number of digits of
>   precision.

Why ReadList can't read this correctly? Is this a bug?

`Import` can get the numbers correct

```
Import[Export["/work/mwu3/temp/1234.dat", " 0.000000000000000000E+00
   0.490953850725349982E-10
   0.135898165173686872E-09
   0.264968686580858939E-09"], "List"]
(*{0.,4.9095385072534998*10^-11,1.3589816517368687*10^-10,2.6496868658085894*10^-10}*)
```

but I have very large data files, `Import` would take forever.
Is there a way to solve it?

Here is my system information:

Mathematica:

9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 20, 2012), ReleaseID -> 9.0.0.0

os :

Linux version 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-022.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 14 15:48:21 EDT 2013

Comment: It works fine on my system. v9.0.1 Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: I can confirm that it works properly in v9.0.1 on Windows 8 and gives your results on v9.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Linux 12.04 64 bit and *Mathematica* 9.0.1 and it works fine here (even on 8.0.4). Can you specify your system in more detail (Linux distribution and version and minor version of *Mathematica*). Furthermore, I think you should definitely contact Wolfram support.

Comment: It gives the incorrect result in v9.0.0 on Linux 13.04 32 bit.

Comment: It works on Fedora 19 64 bit and _Mathematica_ 9.0.1.

Comment: incorrect with 9.0 -- The issue seems to be with the number of digits, take one digit from the numbers and it works.  I think we can fairly call this a bug

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33498/readlist-cant-read-from-file-containing-high-precision-reals)?

Comment: sounds like you should update to 9.0.1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I have corrected it.

Comment: Okay!  I tweaked it slightly to make site-wide searches easier. (I hope.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImportString seems to work:

```
      First@ImportString[
          " 0.000000000000000000E+00 0.490953850725349982E-10 \
            0.135898165173686872E-09 0.264968686580858939E-09", "Table"]
```

(* 
               {0., 4.9095385072534998*10^-11, 1.3589816517368687*10^-10, 
                2.6496868658085894*10^-10}
*)