# How to read long numbers?

Tags: inputfield

Now, I have a data file (abc.dat) and it includes many long-Fortran-like numerical numbers as follows,

```
 6.329743394299864138426200801048403E-0008
-2.549598515596261539775494416553164E-0005
-4.070996338361811028817170114484442E-0005
```

How to read these data in Mathematica? If we use ReadList["abc.dat",Real] and it is not available for these long numbers. If we use ReadList["abc.dat", Record], then we need to find a way to change the string to numbers. Is there some better way for dealing with this problem ?

Comment: Read as text, then use something like `ToExpression[StringReplace[nums, "E" -> "*10^"]]` on that list. However, `ReadList[...,Number]` should handle the Fortran style.

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33498/readlist-cant-read-from-file-containing-high-precision-reals

Comment: In version 7 `ReadList["abc.dat", Real]` appears to work correctly, yielding:  `{6.32974339429986413842620080104840*10^-8, -0.0000254959851559626153977549441655316,
-0.0000407099633836181102881717011448444}`.  What output do you get?

Comment: Also related: [How to convert a string of number into real numbers without precision loss](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38952/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Looks like a *possible* bug in V9...

Comment: @rasher Wait, I think I misunderstood; you think this is *not* a bug then?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: No, I think it is, but I'm loath to call something a bug publicly without others reproducing/confirming it first.

Answer (score 1):

I opened HxD and pasted your numbers and saved as abc.dat. Then this worked for (8.0.4.0):

```
Import["C:\\f1\\f2\\Desktop\\abc.dat"]
(*{{6.32974339429986413842620080104840\[CenterDot]10^-8},{-0.0000254959851559626153977549441655316},{-0.0000407099633836181102881717011448444}}*)
```

Comment: Incidentally in version 7 `Import` does not work fully here: data is imported as machine reals, losing input precision.