# Importing High Precision (22 digits) data from a file

Tags: import, precision-and-accuracy

I want to import list from a file and I am using `ReadList` but my data is in format like this 8.2457409790900004e+08 but it i being imported like $8.24574*10^8$. Is there a way to increase the precision of import? Or even better, is there a way to change the notebook's precision globally ?

Comment: @MichaelE2 doing `FullForm[number]`gives me $8.24574098106`*^8$ which is still not   8.2457409810599995e+08, I would need 22 digits.

Comment: I think the 22 digit requirement is worth putting in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I added it to the title

Comment: Related, perhaps duplicate: [(33498)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33498),
[(38952)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38952).  I'm too tired to answer now; if no one else does in the next day remind me and I shall.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, It is finally solved thank you for help, I also your comments in other posts and also in those that you suggested it helped a lot. Finally this code worked :) `ToExpression /@StringReplace[StringReplace[ReadList["Filename", String],"e" -> "0e"], "e" | "E" :> "*^"]`

Comment: According to [IEEE 754 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Character_representation), §5.12.2, the standard character representation of "binary64" reals (double-precision reals) is 17 digits.  No doubt *Mathematica* interprets your input that way.  It seems likely that the data was written that way, too, unless you have some reason to think differently.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have sufficient precision in your input file to trigger an arbitrary precision representation automatically.  In your example, you just need one more digit as, I believe, one digit past machine doesn't typically do it.

```
ImportString[
  "8.24574097909000040e+08,8.2457409790900004e+08",
  "CSV"]

(* Out: {{8.2457409790900004*10^8, 8.24574*10^8}} *)
```

There's no way to expect this to have 22 digits of precision since you don't have that much in your input.  You can always call `SetPrecision` on the result.

Comment: I can import it as String that is no problem but then again converting the string to Number shows the same problem. In the end I want this value $8.2457409790900004e+08$ but Mathematica is only giving me $8.24574098106‘∗^8$

Comment: @jason There is no import as string in my example. I used `ImportString` since it works exactly as `Import` but allows one to show a whole example without reference to an internal file. If you want that *specific* number, then that specific number will need one more zero in your input file. Keep in mind also that you *should* get the binary number with the specified precision closest to your input, so that trailing digits are often present. I can't verify your  `8.24574098106` as I get `8.24574097909*^8`, which seems quite right.

Comment: yeah I mean, I get the same `8.24574097909*^8` but I miss out on remaining 5 digits `00004` in the end. And it is important to get that too. Is there other ways then adding `0` at the end as the file is quite large.

Comment: @jason You can use `StringReplace`: `ImportString[StringReplace[ReadString[filename], "e" -> "0e"]]` with an appropriate format for `ImportString`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 and @Mark McClure I got it Finally thank you. I did like this `ToExpression /@StringReplace[StringReplace[ReadList["Filename", String],"e" -> "0e"], "e" | "E" :> "*^"]` and it worked with charm. :) But still can you tell me why was it neccessary to add 0 at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the trick of adding a zero only works for numbers in scientific notation:

This is a convoluted approach that works with arbitrary floats:

```
 toarbprecision[string_] := 
     Module[{dp, ep, firstnonzero, mend, pow, dig},
       dp = StringPosition[string, "."][[1, 1]];
       ep = StringPosition[string, "e" | "E"];
       firstnonzero = StringPosition[string, ToString /@ Range[9]][[1, 1]];
       If[ep == {},
         mend = 0; pow = 0,
         mend =  ep[[1, 1]] ;
         pow = ToExpression[ StringTake[string, {mend + 1, -1}]]];
       (* optional to avoid creating arbitrary
              precision representation of low precision numbers
         If[mend-firstnonzero-1<=Round@$MachinePrecision,
            Return[ToExpression@string]];
       *)
       N[FromDigits[{#, 
             dp - firstnonzero + Boole[dp < firstnonzero] + pow}], Length@#] &@
         ToExpression@
          Cases[Characters[StringTake[string, {firstnonzero, mend - 1}]], 
             s_String /; (s != ".")]]
```

Example:

```
 v = N[10^6 Pi, 18];
 Export[ "test.csv", {v, N[v, 17], N[v, $MachinePrecision]}];
 FilePrint["test.csv"]
```

> ```
> 3.14159265358979324e6
> 3.1415926535897932e6
> 3.141592653589793e6
> ```

```
 in = (toarbprecision /@ ReadList[ StringToStream@#, Word,WordSeparators -> {","}]&
   /@ Import["test.csv", {"Text", "Lines"}])
```

> {{3.14159265358979324*10^6}, {3.1415926535897932*10^6}, {3.141592653589793*10^6}}

```
 Precision /@ in
```

> {18., 17., 16.}

Warning I just whipped this up quickly - I'd advise some considerable validation checking before putting it to real use